# Handle error in .GetData() for pivot table when lookup value doesn't exist

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 365 and am doing a look up in some pivot tables using VBA. I encountered an issue when I filter on something and then do a .GetData to query the pivot table and the the thing I am looking up no longer exists. For example, if I were to set up the pivot table so that Item_B is no longer in it and do:

```
pt.GetData("Col_1 Item_B")
```

i would get and error. I tried doing something like the following but it gives a type mismatch error (I am actually getting the data based on label and i.Value which is a part of a range of cells):

```
On Error Resume Next
tVal = .GetData(label & " " & i.Value)
On Error GoTo 0

If CBool(tVal) Is Nothing Then
   i.offset(0, 1).Value = "-"
Else
   i.offset(0, 1).Value = .GetData(label & " " & i.Value)
End If
```

I was messing around with it but have not been able to get around the error. I was hoping someone here could tell me how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this?

```
Dim errorInGettingValue As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
tVal = .GetData(Label & " " & i.Value)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then errorInGettingValue = True '<~~ Check if error happened
On Error GoTo 0

If errorInGettingValue Then
   i.Offset(0, 1).Value = "-"
Else
   i.Offset(0, 1).Value = .GetData(Label & " " & i.Value)
End If
```